# Upload file in xampp using git

Tags: git, xampp

I don't want to upload file in gitLab or gitHub using Git.

I have a file named "test.php" in myProject folder located in D drive.
Now I want to upload this file in my local server ( XAMPP ) in C drive using Git.
How can I do it !!!
Please explain it.

Comment: No !dea !!!! Oh man that's horrible

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here are the steps required

1. Create a new project `C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject`
2. Go to `C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject`
3. Run in that directory from the shell: `git init` then `git config --local receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead`
4. Now go to your `D:/` drive
5. Run in that directory from the shell: `git clone C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject`
6. Now you have your project on your local server, and you can clone the repo from anywhere in your system.

Comment: Shell says :
fatal : ' C:/xampp/htdocs/gitProject ' doesn't appear to be a git repository
fatal : Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and repository exists